# Reading armature from a file

Tags: python, animation

I am trying to read an armature from this file format, anyone has any idea how to contruct bone location and roatation from these?
https://github.com/DummkopfOfHachtenduden/SilkroadDoc/wiki/JMXVBSK
in other words **I have a hirearchy of bones and these information, how do I reconstruct it**

what I tried:

1. Read all bones from file and setting their world transformation (didn't use relative transformations at all)
2. Set parent for each bone

it almost worked, however some bones had a different location, so supposidly the correct way is to somehow mix these matrices

I have some work in progress code here:
https://github.com/iyadahmed/blender_ban_importer

[image]